# Invoking getQueueUrl() on FIFO Queue with SSE Enabled Results in 403 / All requests to this queue must use HTTPS and SigV4

Tags: amazon-sqs, amazon-iam, aws-java-sdk

I am using a SQS FIFO queue with SSE enabled.  When I use a SQS client to call getQueueUrl(), an exception is thrown with the message `All requests to this queue must use HTTPS and SigV4.`

Using the latest version of the aws-java-sdk:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.160</version>
    </dependency>
```

The following code reproduces the issue:

```
public class SimpleSqsClient {

    private static ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration() {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfiguration.setProxyHost("proxy.foo.com");
        clientConfiguration.setProxyPort(8099);
        clientConfiguration.setProxyUsername("username");
        clientConfiguration.setProxyPassword("password");
        clientConfiguration.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
        clientConfiguration.setPreemptiveBasicProxyAuth(false);

        return clientConfiguration;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        /*
         * The ProfileCredentialsProvider will return your [default] credential
         * profile by reading from the credentials file located at
         * (~/.aws/credentials).
         */
        AWSCredentials credentials = null;
        try {
            credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmazonClientException("Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. "
                    + "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct "
                    + "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.", e);
        }

        AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().withClientConfiguration(clientConfiguration())
                .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider("SOME_PROFILE"))
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();

        System.out.println("===========================================");
        System.out.println("Simple SQS Test");
        System.out.println("===========================================\n");
        try {

            System.out.println(sqs.getQueueUrl("some-sse-enabled-queue.fifo"));

        } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
            System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it "
                    + "to Amazon SQS, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.");
            System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
            System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
            System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
        } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
            System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, which means the client encountered "
                    + "a serious internal problem while trying to communicate with SQS, such as not "
                    + "being able to access the network.");
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it to Amazon SQS, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.
Error Message:    All requests to this queue must use HTTPS and SigV4. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidSecurity; Request ID: ...)
HTTP Status Code: 403
AWS Error Code:   InvalidSecurity
Error Type:       Client
Request ID:       ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
clientConfiguration.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);
```

to

```
clientConfiguration.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);
```

Resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

I landed here while troubleshooting *All requests to this queue must use HTTPS and SigV4* error in Celery.

IN my case it was setting:

```
broker_transport_options = {
    "is_secure": True,
    ...
}
```

Leaving it here in case anyone else will land here in similar predicament.

Comment: Can you share your complete configuration? I am stuck with this using Celery. My configuration works with HTTP but when I switch to HTTPS it fails.

Comment: I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for complete configuration

```
class CeleryConfig:
broker_url: str = "sqs://"
task_default_queue: str = ENV_QUEUE_NAME
task_create_missing_queues: bool = False
worker_enable_remote_control: bool = False
worker_send_task_events: bool = False
broker_transport_options = {
    "is_secure": True,
    'predefined_queues': {
        ENV_QUEUE_NAME: {
            'url': base_url + ENV_QUEUE_NAME,
        },
    },
}
celery = Celery("WorkerName", backend=RESULT_BACKEND)
celery.config_from_object(CeleryConfig)
```